# Does using Pattern.LITERAL mean the same as Pattern.quote?

Tags: java, regex

More precisely: Do

```
Pattern.compile(s, x | Pattern.LITERAL)
```

and

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s), x)
```

create equivalent regexes for any String `s` and any other flag `x`?

If not, how to simulate Pattern.LITERAL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the question as is, the answer is no, because of setting x=Pattern.LITERAL leading to quoting `s` twice in the second expression. With double quoting and `s="A"` the String `"A"` won't be matched, but the String `"\\QA\\E"` will. However,

```
Pattern.compile(s, x | Pattern.LITERAL)
```

seem to be equivalent to

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s), x & ~Pattern.LITERAL)
```

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: For your example, yes.

Long answer: Yes, but Pattern.quote is more flexible. What if you only wanted *some* of your pattern quoted? Like:

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s) + "+", x)
```

With setting the Pattern.LITERAL flag, even the `+` character would now be treated literally.

If you don't trust the documentation, maybe looking at [the source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#lM3pwaU8RUc/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java&q=Pattern%5C.java%20function%3acompile&l=1471) at Google Code Search for `Pattern.compile` will help.

From what I can derive from looking at the source code:

- If the LITERAL flag is **not** set, regardless of all the other flags, it will look for any \Q...\E quoted blocks and manually escape special characters, just as one would expect.
- If the LITERAL flag is set, it will convert the whole pattern using the [newSlice](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#lM3pwaU8RUc/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java&q=Pattern%5C.java%20function%3acompile&l=3082) method, and there are special cases for at least the `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag and `UNICODE_CASE` flag

Comment: You said "yes", but gave no reason for it. And I know about the flexibility.

Comment: @maaartinus I was about to write out an example to prove it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not see a problem with it, I don’t quite trust applying arbitrary pattern flags together with whole-pattern quoted stuff. The [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#LITERAL) mentions that it renders all flags but two superfluous, after all. I *think* it would be ok, but color me *méfiant* — mistrusting.

Have you tried using `\Q … \E` on just those parts of the pattern that you wish quoted into non–meta‐ness, so to speak?

Comment: I've read the documentation twice and it's unclear. The two descriptions are similar but not identical, OTOH, I see no real difference. In the documentation for quote they write "as if it were a literal pattern", and there's nothing about case. I know \Q..\E, and that's how Pattern.quote actually works.