# How do I sanitize input before making a regex out of it?

Tags: java, regex, sanitization

I'm making a Java program that parses the user's input with a regex. For instance, if the user inputs `/me eats`, it should match the `/me` and replace it with `<move>`. However, Java isn't properly matching because `/` is a special character to regexes. **How do I automatically replace all the various special Java regex characters with escapes?**

For instance:

- `/me` becomes `\/me`
- `*` becomes `\*`
- `[` becomes `\[`
- and so on...

*before* it's put into `Pattern.compile`.

This is not a command system. I am allowing users to specify how to denote a roleplaying move. If it helps, here is a mockup of how the user specifies what they consider a roleplay move:

[image: A mockup of the preferences pane that would control this system]

Comment: I'm not sure if this would match your needs, but perhaps [Pattern#quote()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) would work for you? What it does is produces a `Pattern` that ignores all metacharacters/escapes, so I *think* you'd be able to match `/me` without escapes

Comment: Also, if you only need to do straight string replacement (and don't actually need regular expressions), probably you could use the `String#replace(CharSequence target,CharSequence replacement)` overload.

Comment: Actually, I'm a little confused... Are you making a regex out of the user's input or matching the user's input with a regex? Because `/me` isn't valid regex from what I know...

Comment: you don't need to escape the slash, it is not a special character. It can be a little confusing since it is often used as pattern delimiter with other languages.

Comment: "I'm making a java program that parses the user's input with a regex". What you describe is a program that *uses* the user's input *as* a regex, after a little light mangling. Please clarify.

Comment: @AndrewMedico @user3580294 @EJP I'm making a regex like `/(?<=\/me).*?/i` or `/(?<=\*).*?(?=\*)/gi` to extract parts of the user's future input, but also letting the user dictate what delimiters to use instead of `/me` or `*`

Comment: "`/` is a special character to regexes".  Not in Java it isn't.

Comment: FYI, made small correction for the backslash character itself.

Comment: @MikeSamuel then how come `Pattern.compile("/me").matcher("/me eats").find()` returns `false`?

Comment: @Supuhstar, it returns true when I run it under java version 1.6.0_65.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I'm programming in Java 7.... and now it prints `true`... I'm gonna kick myself if this is because I didn't clean my targets or something

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Supuhstar, I believe this is the one-liner you're looking for (see [online demo](http://ideone.com/feZMxj)):

```
String sanitized = subject.replaceAll("[-.\\+*?\\[^\\]$(){}=!<>|:\\\\]", "\\\\$0");
```

This adds a backslash to all of the following characters:

```
. + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : - \
```

**Test Input:** `String subject = ".+*?[^]$(){}=!<>|:-\\";`

**Output:** `\.\+\*\?\[\^\]\$\(\)\{\}\=\!\<\>\|\:-\\`

Next, as you wanted, you can proceed with:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(sanitized);
```

**Notes:**

1. Like Perl and PHP, Java also has a syntax to escape an entire string: you place it between `\Q` and `\E`. That is what `Pattern.quote` does for you, but it quotes more text than you want for your situation.
2. This is only one possible solution answering your specific requirement of adding a backslash. For more options, also see [Does using Pattern.LITERAL mean the same as Pattern.quote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839894/does-using-pattern-literal-mean-the-same-as-pattern-quote)

Comment: alright, this works for `* ... *`, but `Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=" + "/me".replaceAll("[.\\+*?\\[^\\]$(){}=!<>|:-\\\\]", "\\\\$0") + ").*?").matcher("/me eats"); System.out.println(m.find()); System.out.println(m.group());` prints `true` and then the empty string

Comment: @Supuhstar Yes, you have a small typo in your regex. :) The `?` in your `.*?` makes the dot-star lazy, so it will not bother to match anything after the lookbehind succeeds. See the [updated demo](http://ideone.com/feZMxj) where I removed the `?` And also you can check it interactively on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/aT7vT0), here with the `?` it doesn't match, remove the `?` and it will match. Other than that, glad to hear it's working for you. :)

Comment: I thought `.*?` meant "match any number of any character, but as few as possible"... man, regexes are hard. Thank you.

Comment: `I thought .*? meant "match any number of any character, but as few as possible` Yes, you got it right... the key to understand is that `as few as possible` can mean zero characters. So with the `?`, the regex matches (the lookbehind succeeds), but it is a "zero-width match", because there is no character to report. That is why you were getting the `true` and the empty string.

Comment: You've got a problem here. You forgot to escape the `-`. I had a pattern syntax runtime exception with uppercase letters like `M` because ":-\\" means **a single character in the range between the following two characters**: `:` and `\\ `. So the valid pattern for this problem is a `"[.\\+*?\\[^\\]$(){}=!<>|:\\-\\\\]"`

Comment: Sorry about the runtime exception part. I can no longer edit the comment. The exception was thrown due to using escaped sequence in a regex. E.g. uppercase `M` was escaped like `\M`, but that is not directly related to the problem and is useless mentioning here.

Comment: @DoctororDrive No time to check, but I'll take your word for it. Edited the answer and placed the `-` at the front of the charclass. Many engines recognize when a range doesn't make sense, don't recall what Java does.

Comment: @zx81 The service at http://regex101.com recognizes that as a range as well as Java.

Comment: @DoctororDrive You're right (I had time to fire up Java and check all the way back to Java4). Good catch. Moving the `-` to the front (which I usually do) fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work but how about:

```
String inputString = ....
inputString = Pattern.compile(inputString, Pattern.LITERAL).pattern();
//process inputString now
```

Currently untested. Will remove answer if not actually correct.

Comment: `System.out.println(Pattern.compile("(?<=" + Pattern.quote("/me") + ").*?").matcher("/me eats").matches());` prints `false`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

```
public String quote(String input) {
    return Pattern.quote(input).substring(2, input.length() + 2); // quote() adds '\Q' and '\E', substring used to remove those.
}
String input = "/me eats";
String cmd = input.replaceAll(quote("/me"), /* replacement */);
```

Now then, I'm assuming this is a command system, in which case I would recommend against using regex for your parsing.

Typically, this is done in a much simpler manner with `/command <arguments>...`:

```
public class Command {

    private final String name;
    private final String[] args;

    public Command(String name, String... args) {
        this.name = name;
        this.args = args;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String[] getArgs() {
        return this.args;
    }

}
```

An example of this usage:

```
String commandPrefix = "/";
String input = "/me eats";
if (input.startsWith(commandPrefix)) {
    String[] raw = input.split(" ");
    Command cmd = new Command(raw[0].substring(commandPrefix.length(), raw[0].length(), Arrays.copyOfRange(raw, 1, raw.length - 1);
    //cmd.getName() -> "me"
    //cmd.getArgs() -> ["eats"]
}
```

By throwing this to something that determines how to execute the command, you can simply handle the `me` command like so:

```
public void onCommand(Command cmd) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (String s : cmd.getArgs()) {
        if (first) { first = false; } else { sb.append(" "); }
        sb.append(s);
    }
    String action = sb.toString();
    //use the "action" string in whatever 3rd person context you desire.
}
```

Comment: This is not a command system. I am allowing users to specify how to denote a roleplaying move. If it helps, here is a mockup of how the user specifies what they consider a roleplay move: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1hlvw2FpkLHvn3InYo3SG7ewxn8y3Z3MAgj3G_Ja_lDo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sounds like a command to me (/me is used in IRC, where it's parsed through a command system for most clients). I'll add an example of how this would be handled in a command system.

Comment: if you read my whole question and look at the drawing I sent you, you'll see that `/me` is arbitrary and can be replaced by `* ... *`, `//`, `- ... -`, `--`, or anything else the user wants.

Comment: Then if you want you can still use the Pattern quoting. Even if it is arbitrary, you can still implement it under a similar but modified system.

Comment: @Supuhstar As your question is written, it looks like `Pattern.quote` will 100% work. Can you please elaborate a bit on how / why it won't? Perhaps include some actual code with expected output.

Comment: @Dukeling It seems Pattern.quote works fine when I use `.*` instead of `.*?`. However, since your answer deals with command processing when that isn't the nature of my question, I can't accept it right now. It's a very nice answer abotu command processing, but still irrelevant; this is not a command system, and I'm okay with `/me` being used in the beginning of the string to be parsed, just like `* ... *` could.

Comment: I offered an alternative along with an answer. It's not irrelevant in my opinion, as it is very applicable to abstracting the system.

Comment: @Rogue agreed, it's quite nice for abstracting a command-based system. However, as I said, `/me` is not a command in this system, but a delimiter. It can appear in the middle of the message and have the same effect.

Comment: This would not quote chars like + adn *, would it?